# Custom function for insert/update SQL with C#

Tags: c#, mysql

sorry if this argument was already treated but I didn't find anything.

I'm writing a program that have many insert/update query, my problem is that I don't like so much writing query with String.Format method like:

```
query = "INSERT INTO righe_comanda (id_originale, quantita, nome, prezzo, id_comanda,";
query += "variazionipositive,variazioninegative,opzioneselezionata,evaso, data_evasione, user_evasione) VALUES";
query += "({0},{1},'{2}','{3}',{4},'{5}','{6}','{7}',{8},'{9}','{10}');";
query = String.Format(query, id_originale, quantita, nome, prezzo, ID_Comanda, VariazioniPositive, VariazioniNegative, OpzioneSelezionata, Evaso, DataEvasione, UserEvasione);
```

It is easy to make an error of number of arguments, with ' ', and so on. So I wrote a function that create the query automatically. See:

```
public static string QueryFormat(string nometabella, string modalita, Dictionary<string, string> parametri, string where_column = null, string where_value = null)
    {
        string query = "";

        if (modalita == "INSERT")
        {
            query += "INSERT INTO " + nometabella + " (";
            foreach (var item in parametri)
            {
                query += item.Key + ", ";
            }
            query = query.Substring(0, query.Length - 2);
            query += ") VALUES (";
            foreach (var item in parametri)
            {
                query += GestisciValore(item.Value) + ", ";
            }
            query = query.Substring(0, query.Length - 2);
            query += ")";
        }
        else if (modalita == "UPDATE")
        {
            query += "UPDATE " + nometabella + " SET ";
            foreach (var item in parametri)
            {
                query += item.Key + " = " + GestisciValore(item.Value) + ", ";
            }
            query = query.Substring(0, query.Length - 2);
            query += " WHERE " + where_column + " = " + GestisciValore(where_value);
        }
        return query;
    }
    private static string GestisciValore(string valore)
    {
        int n;
        if (int.TryParse(valore, out n))
            return valore;
        else
            return "'" + valore + "'";
    }
```

What do you think about this? There is any alternative?

Regards

Comment: As there is no problems with your code, I think this would be better asked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. The only thing I would add is from a security standpoint. If any of the variables involved here are ever exposed to user input, you are open for sql injection. That being said, you weren't properly parameterizing your SQL to begin with, so the hole was already there. You should read up on [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html)

Comment: My personal option: If you don't want to write SQL, use an ORM (e.g. Entity Framework). If your want to write SQL yourself, use some kind of "SQL query builder" that ensures that at least parameters are escaped, e.g. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html but hey, "I want to write SQL mysql but I don't want to write so much SQL"... - know what I mean? ;-)

Comment: Better you use some ORM such as Entity Framework to avoid all the trouble